# How to tell git to ignore global config

Tags: git

[The Git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config---global) talk about the default global git config file locations (`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` or `~/.gitconfig`), but don't offer a way to tell a git command to ignore that file.

I'm looking for an environment variable, maybe called `$GIT_CONFIG_NOGLOBAL` (similar to [`$GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-GITCONFIGNOSYSTEM)), or a flag to pass to git commands (for example `--ignore-global-config`). I need it because my standard git settings (especially `commit.gpgsign true`) interfere with test suites that use git.

If it's not currently possible I can raise an issue on their issue tracker.

Comment: Set `$HOME` or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to an alternate value while running the command. It's a bit brute-force (you might need all the *other* config files to remain configured) but that's one way to deal with it. Or, run tests as a user that does not have a configuration; or stick with plumbing commands, which generally don't *read* any configuration items, which is why they're the commands to use in scripts.

Comment: You can run a command with a temporarily set envvar like so: `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM=1 git do thing`.

Comment: Why do you have test suites that use git? Seems like you're testing git?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen see for example the npm test suite (although there are others).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another approach, with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), is to use the new `GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM`:

Git 2.32 replaces `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM` mechanism to decline from reading the system-wide configuration file with **`GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM` that lets users specify from which file to read the system-wide configuration (setting it to an empty file would essentially be the same as setting NOSYSTEM)**, and introduce `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` to override the per-user configuration in `$HOME/.gitconfig`.

See [commit 482d549](https://github.com/git/git/commit/482d5499067b2a1fc8d1ebfb5160022dc23ab136) (23 Apr 2021), and [commit 4179b48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4179b4897f2de28858acaebd6382c06c91532e98), [commit 1e06eb9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e06eb9b5dc9c663c2a60a2ca63e218b41a765e8), [commit c62a999](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c62a999c6e595692ee3bd8ff1e9435491872a79c) (19 Apr 2021) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e706aaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e706aaf3bc8ad97877cbf21887f96c5af66c7562), 07 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4179b4897f2de28858acaebd6382c06c91532e98): allow overriding of global and system configuration
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> In order to have git run in a fully controlled environment without any misconfiguration, it may be desirable for users or scripts to override global- and system-level configuration files.
> We already have a way of doing this, which is to unset both HOME and `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variables and to set `GIT_CONFIG_NOGLOBAL=true`.
> This is quite kludgy, and unsetting the first two variables likely has an impact on other executables spawned by such a script.
>
> The obvious way to fix this would be to introduce `GIT_CONFIG_NOGLOBAL` as an equivalent to `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM`.
> But in the past, it has turned out that this design is inflexible: we cannot test system-level parsing of the git configuration in our test harness because there is no way to change its location, so all tests run with `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM` set.
>
> Instead of doing the same mistake with `GIT_CONFIG_NOGLOBAL`, introduce two new variables `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` and `GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM`:
>
> - If unset, git continues to use the usual locations.
> - If set to a specific path, we skip reading the normal configuration files and instead take the path.
>   By setting the path to `/dev/null`, no configuration will be loaded for the respective level.
>
> This implements the usecase where we want to execute code in a sanitized environment without any potential misconfigurations via `/dev/null`, but is more flexible and allows for more usecases than simply adding `GIT_CONFIG_NOGLOBAL`.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4179b4897f2de28858acaebd6382c06c91532e98/Documentation/git-config.txt#L343-L347):

> ### `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL`
>
> ### `GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM`
>
> Take the configuration from the given files instead from global or
> system-level configuration.

`git` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4179b4897f2de28858acaebd6382c06c91532e98/Documentation/git.txt#L673-L682):

> ### `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL`
>
> ### `GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM`
>
> Take the configuration from the given files instead from global or
> system-level configuration files. If `GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM` is set, the
> system config file defined at build time (usually `/etc/gitconfig`)
> will not be read. Likewise, if `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` is set, neither
> `$HOME/.gitconfig` nor `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` will be read. Can
> be set to `/dev/null` to skip reading configuration files of the
> respective level.

---

Example, [baltakatei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10850071/baltakatei) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881807/how-to-tell-git-to-ignore-global-config/67512433#comment128661708_67512433), possibly in [this context](https://twitter.com/baltakatei/status/1543367397804937216):

> Running `export GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=''; export GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM=''` before running `make` allowed me to compile a program that expects `git log -1 --pretty=oneline somefile` to get a commit hash when I have `log.showsignature=true` in my `~/.gitconfig` file.
> (`git log-1 --pretty=oneline` can print more than one line depending on what's in `gitconfig` files).
> Context: compiling [Kaldi](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi), a speech transcription program.

Comment: You saved me. Running `export GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=''; GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM` before running `make` allowed me to compile a program that expects `git log -1 --pretty=oneline somefile` to get a commit hash when I have `log.showsignature=true` in my `~/.gitconfig` file (`git log-1 --pretty=oneline` can print more than one line depending on what's in gitconfig files).

Comment: @baltakatei Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment for illustration in the answer.

Comment: Whoops, it should have been `export GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=''; export GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM=''`. And the context was compiling Kaldi, a speech transcription program. https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi

Comment: @baltakatei OK, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

> *I need it because my standard git settings (especially commit.gpgsign true) interfere with test suites that use git.*

I'd call that a bug in the test suites. They should be set up to ignore outside configs. I'd suggest reporting this to the test suite authors. They'd do the same thing you'd do:

> GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM

> Whether to skip reading settings from the system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig file. This environment variable can be used along with $HOME and
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME to create a predictable environment for a picky script, or you
> can set it temporarily to avoid using a buggy /etc/gitconfig file while waiting
> for someone with sufficient permissions to fix it.

Set `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM`, unset `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, change `$HOME`.

---

[@Pockets commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881807/how-to-tell-git-to-ignore-global-config/43882168?noredirect=1#comment74799506_43882168) with a link to the [Git test suite](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/test-lib.sh) where you can see all the many things they do to ensure Git is isolated.

Comment: You should also set `GIT_ATTR_NOSYSTEM` (and if you have other global configs, such as those for Git templates, those should also be unset/reconfigured). For reference, the Git test suite uses [this script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/test-lib.sh) to prepare the environment for all tests.

Comment: Yes, the plan was to update the test suites, not for me to run the command every time myself.

Unfortunately changing home breaks quite a lot of other tooling, so we'd have to mock up a home directory, which is a bit involved. Thanks for confirming though.

Comment: @gib An alternative is to use a libgit2 wrapper library. That should give you more control over where it reads the config. It is simpler to program than constantly having to shell out to git and parse the results. I do that for most git automation. There is a steep learning curve to using libgit2, but a good wrapper library will provide familiar methods.

Answer (score 1):

Using docker, you can isolate without setting variables.

```sh
docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd)":/work:ro -w /work alpine sh -c 'apk add git && git status'
```

For your test suites, you could do the same by having a Dockerfile (omitted here because I don't know your test situation) that sets up your test framework + git and run it similarly.

If you need to also provide ssh credentials to git and you are using [ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent), you can also mount the ssh auth socket:

```sh
docker run -it --rm \
  -v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent --env SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent \
  -v "$(pwd)":/work:ro -w /work test_runner
```